# Из-за чего не устанавливается vmware tools в ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

Хост ubuntu 19.04.
Гостевая система windows 10 pro.
При попытке установки tools возникает ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного не по теме: почему не VBox?

Comment: А в Vbox как настроить высокую производительность 3D карты? По скорости работы вижу vmware значительно быстрее.

Comment: Сам не тыкал, но вроде вбокс через шелл умеет пробрасывать pci-express железки. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough Типа того.

Comment: По теме. `open-vm-tools-desktop` ставил?

Comment: Да. Ставятся хорошо в ubuntu. Но сама vmware должна скачивать tools конкретные под гостевую винду и сама их ставить из этой винды. А тут сбой на этапе скачивания. Запрашивает пароль и потом пишет об ошибке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если судить по названию устанавливаемого ПО, то оно и не должно было бы установиться на Ubuntu, ибо сделано для Окошек "VMware Tools for **Windows Vista**"

Comment: Это автоматически предлагается к установке в момент запуска гостевой системы.

Comment: В общем установил из самой гостевой windows. Через сам Vmware не ставится хотя и предлагается к установке.